# the order of $a + \mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

If $\frac{8}{9} + \mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, then the order of $\frac{8}{9} + \mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is 9 and similarly the order of $\frac{9}{8} + \mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is 8.

For the case of $a + \mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Since $a + \mathbb{Z}\equiv 0 + \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$, then the order of $a + \mathbb{Z}$ is zero.  Is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it's not. The order of the identity element is 1.

Comment: @Anubhab so if $a$ is an arbitrary integer, then what should the order of the coset $a + \mathbb{Z}$ be?

Comment: @Anubhab would the order be 1?

Comment: I have to admit -sheepishly- that I agree with @Anubhab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take this off the unanswered q:

No, if $a$ is an integer, the coset $a+\mathbb{Z}$ is the same as the coset $\mathbb{Z}$, which is the identity in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, and so has order $1$.

The other assertions in the original post [at the time of writing this answer!] are correct.

Comment: thank you for that.  :)

Comment: This is not true. The order of the identity is 1 and not 0.

Comment: @Anubhab eek you are right! how embarassing. Please correct the above.

Comment: @Anubhab and I can't even spell embarrassing.

Comment: @peterag lol yeah, happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 2):

The order of $a+\Bbb Z$ in the quotient $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $na\in\Bbb Z$. So, if  $a\in\Bbb Z$, then $n=1$. (Btw, you can check that this lemma proves the two claims in the opening of your post.)

Comment: thank you for clearing that up for me.